# How do I delete exiting structures on a structure block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am a map creator, and it's kinda hard to find structures when you have a lot saved on your laptop. So, I have a question and might need your help:

**How do I remove structures** on a structure block?

Things I tried:

- Typing `/clear`
- tried scripting it
- tried to go to system files but nothing worked

Comment: What do you mean, "remove structures"? Do you have e.g. 10 structures and they're all displayed in the structure block, but you only want 5 of them to be displayed?

Comment: yes kind of some say i need to use '/clear' but it doesn't work

Comment: They read the files stored at `.minecraft/saves/<wordname>/generated/minecraft/structures`, so deleting/moving them from there should work. Have you tried re-opening the world or the game?

Comment: oh thanks it worked thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They read the files stored at
> .`minecraft/saves/<wordname>/generated/minecraft/structures`, so
> deleting/moving them from there should work. Have you tried re-opening
> the world or the game?

Source: [mindoverflow's comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/391311/how-do-i-delete-exiting-structures-on-a-structure-block/#comment550002_391311)